# Does The Clear Method On A Collection Release The Event Subscriptions?

Tags: c#, collections

I have a collection

```
private ObservableCollection<Contact> _contacts;
```

In the constructor of my class I create it

```
_contacts = new ObservableCollection<Contact>();
```

I have methods to add and remove items from my collection. I want to track changes to the entities in my collection which implement the IPropertyChanged interface so I subscribe to their PropertyChanged event.

```
public void AddContact(Contact contact)
{
    ((INotifyPropertyChanged)contact).PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(Contact_PropertyChanged);
    _contacts.Add(contact);
}

public void AddContact(int index, Contact contact)
{
    ((INotifyPropertyChanged)contact).PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(Contact_PropertyChanged);
    _contacts.Insert(index, contact);
}
```

When I remove an entity from the collection, I unsubscribe from the PropertyChanged event. I am told this is to allow the entity to be garbage collected and not create memory issues.

```
public void RemoveContact(Contact contact)
{
    ((INotifyPropertyChanged)contact).PropertyChanged -= Contact_PropertyChanged;
    _contacts.Remove(contact);
}
```

So, I hope this is all good. Now, I need to clear the collection in one of my methods. My first thought would be to call `_contacts.Clear()`. Then I got to wondering if this releases those event subscriptions? Would I need to create my own clear method? Something like this:

```
public void ClearContacts()
{
    foreach(Contact contact in _contacts)
    {
        this.RemoveContact(contact);
    }
}
```

I am hoping one of the .NET C# experts here could clear this up for me or tell me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clear() does not remove event handlers.  (Note also, that calling Clear() does not trip a CollectionChanged event as Add() and Remove() do.)

Comment: RE: Clear() not tipping a PropertyChanged.

Are you sure about that? Looking at the code for ObservableCollection<T> with Reflector shows that it is calling OnPropertyChanged for both "Count" and "Item[]", same as in Add/Remove, inside the ClearItems() method, which Clear() calls.

Comment: D'oh! I meant CollectionChanged event.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a handler for the `CollectionChanged` event of the `ObservableCollection`, this will work well for unhooking the item event handlers when they are removed and that does get fired when you do a `Clear`, but the problem is the `e.OldItems` collection will be null upon the `Clear()`.

So to agree with @Michael, to do what you want you will have to implement your own Clear method, maybe as an extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void ClearEx(this ObservableCollection<object> collection)
    {
        //custom clear logic...   
    }
}
```

in your clear function you could iterate over the items and clear the event handlers before calling the regular `Clear()` function.

Answer (score 0):

`Clear()` will not release those event subscriptions.

It would probably be best to your own **Clear** method that iterates over the collection removing the event handlers and then calls `Clear()` on the collection.

The reason to do this, instead of calling `Remove()` for each item is that, internally, `Remove()` iterates over the collection in order to find the index of the item you are removing and performance could suffer if there are a large number of items in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code from Reflector:

```
protected override void ClearItems()
{
    this.CheckReentrancy();
    base.ClearItems();
    this.OnPropertyChanged("Count");
    this.OnPropertyChanged("Item[]");
    this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
}
```

It checks to make sure that one of the event handlers hasn't called it in a loop, calls the base `Collection`'s `Clear` function, notifies the subscribers that properties have changed, and finally notifies subscribers that the collection has changed.

At no point does it clear either of the event handlers.